# How to extract folder from .gitignore?

Tags: python, django, git, github, gitignore

Folks, I've deleted my own `django` project by accident and then cloned it from Github. But the problem is that before pushing I've added my virtual environment folder to `.gitignore` and now can't extract/use/activate it. What can I do sometimes ?

Comment: The .gitignore file tells git to ignore certain files and directories from version control. If your venv was referenced in the .gitignore file then it would have been ignored when pushing to github. You can remove the reference to your venv by editing .gitignore, but unless you have a backup of the file, I am afraid that it is gone.

Comment: You shouldn't really be adding your virtual environment to git anyway. Just recreate it from your requirements files.

Comment: Bob, can you be more clear in your question? Please update it to state (1) whether you deleted your virtual environment folder along with your project, and (2) are you asking how to get the environment back or how to remove it from `.gitignore` so that in the future it is saved in git?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question clearly, you have cloned your own **GitHub** repo from your profile, but in your `.gitignore` file, you have specified that you did not want to include the virtual environment folder **in git**.

If that is the case, then I am sorry man, it was probably deleted along with your project, and it won't be in your fresh clone because its not in git, just as you asked.

But you should be able to recreate it pretty easily I would think, since if I remember correctly all the details should be in your python `requirements.txt`, right?

I hope this helps you.

Comment: The question is not about file `.env` but about Python virtual environment. But the answer is valid — there is no way, the environment must be rebuild anew.

Comment: Oh, okay. Hope at least I confirmed your concern.

Comment: fixed. If you are a pythonista, please correct the last bit if I got it wrong.